# How to increase cache disk space in CentOS?

Tags: centos, disk-usage, cache

I have been facing an insufficient space issue in the `/var/cache/yum` directory. Due to this problem, my CentOS graphical user interface crashes. I want to increase the size of the cache directory and also find out the actual size of the cache directory on the servers.

Comment: You do not increase the size of a directory. Instead you increase the size of the disk partition the <directory> resides on. And I'm certain [that has been asked before.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=+increase+partition+size)

Comment: Do you use LVM?

Comment: It is unclear how insufficient space for that specific directory causes the GUI to crash. Is it possibly the `/var` partition that is running out of space when you use `yum`, and that the GUI crashes due to this? If so, the solution is to increase the space for that partition, not necessarily for the `cache` directory specifically. Alternatively, clear out the cache, or make `yum` use some other cache directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may find out the actual usage of the directory "/var/cache/yum" with

```
du -sh /var/cache/yum
```

IMHO there are two options for you:

1. use a different partition, and mount it over /var/cache/yum.
   To do so, add a new parition to the system (eg. adding another distk) and mount it via

   mount -t   /var/cache/yum

Keep in mind, that if you mount a partition over an existing directory (= mount point) then the original content is not available (= not visible) as long as the mount persists. So if you want to have the old content in the new directory, i recommend renaming the old directory first, and then copy the data after the mount.

2. find out, where yum stores its cache configuration, and change it to point to a "bigger" partition with enough space. I cannot help there, since i dont know yum..

Good luck,
Gerhard